# How can I de-obfuscate or decode this Perl code?

Tags: perl, eval

I found this code and I think it's encoded. I tried to understand how it's encoded or how can read it. Does anyone have an idea to decode this code?

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

eval unpack u=>q{_<')I;G0@(EQN7&5<>#5"7'@S,UQX,S-<>#9$7'@U-UQX-C%<>#<R7'@V15QX-CE<>#9%7'@V-UQX,C!<>#4Y_7'@V1EQX-S5<>#(P7'@T1%QX-C%<>#<Y7'@R,%QX-$5<>#8U7'@V-5QX-C1<>#(P7'@U-%QX-D9<>#(P7'@T_.5QX-D5<>#<S7'@W-%QX-C%<>#9#7'@V0UQX,C!<>#<S7'@V1EQX-D1<>#8U7'@P05QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX_,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX-$1<>#9&7'@V-%QX-S5<>#9#7'@V-5QX-S-<>#!!7'@R,%QX,C!<_>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@T.%QX-C5<>#<R7'@V-5QX,C!<>#8Y7'@W,UQX,C!<>#0Q_7'@V15QX,C!<>#0U7'@W.%QX-C%<>#9$7'@W,%QX-D-<>#8U7'@S05QX,$%<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R_,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#8S7'@W,%QX-C%<>#9%7'@R,%QX-$5<>#8U7'@W-%QX,T%<>#-!7'@T.5QX_-3!<>#!!7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@V,UQX-S!<>#8Q7'@V15QX,C!<_>#1#7'@U-UQX-3!<>#-!7'@S05QX-35<>#<S7'@V-5QX-S)<>#0Q7'@V-UQX-C5<>#9%7'@W-%QX,$%<>#(P_7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#8S7'@W,%QX-C%<>#9%7'@R,%QX-35<>#4R7'@T_.5QX,T%<>#-!7'@U-%QX-CE<>#<T7'@V0UQX-C5<>#!!7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX_,C!<>#(P7'@U-%QX-CA<>#8Q7'@V15QX-D)<>#(P7'@W.5QX-D9<>#<U7'@R,%QX-#9<>#9&7'@W,EQX,C!<_>#4U7'@W,UQX-CE<>#9%7'@V-UQX,C!<>#1$7'@W.5QX,C!<>#4S7'@V,UQX-S)<>#8Y7'@W,%QX-S1<>#!!_7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@R,%QX,C!<>#(P7'@V.5QX-D5<>#9!7'@S,UQX-C-<>#<T7'@V_1EQX-S)<>#,S7&5<>#5",%QX-D1<;B(["B-S;&5E<"@B,2(I.PIU<V4@3F5T.CI)4#L*=7-E(%1E<FTZ.D%._4TE#;VQO<CL*=7-E($Q74#HZ57-E<D%G96YT.PIU<V4@55)).CI4:71L92!Q=R@@=&ET;&4@*3L*=7-E('9A_<G,@<7<H("104D]'("D["FUY($!I<%]T96%M("`]("@I.PIM>2`D4%)/1R`]("0P.PHC57-A9V4*(VEF("@@_0$%21U8@/3T@,"`I('L*(R`@("`@("`@<')I;G0@(EQE6S0U;55S86=E.B`N+R104D]'(%MF:6QE72!;5$A2_14%$4UT@6U1)345/551=(%M/5510551=7&Y%>&%M<&QE('!E<FP@)#`@.3`N,"XR,RXU-"`Y,2XP+C4P+C`@_,3(P,"`Q(&QO;%QN:6YJ,V-T;W(S7&XB.PH@(R`@(&5X:70["B-]"FUY("1I<',@/2`D05)'5ELP73L*;W!E_;B!M>2`D:&%N9&QE+"`B7'@S0R(L("1I<',["F-H;VUP*"!M>2!`;&]A9&QI<W0@/2`\)&AA;F1L93X@*3LC_/#T]/3T]/3T]/3T]/3T]($]014X@55`@25!3"F-L;W-E("1H86YD;&4["@IM>2`D=&AR96%D<R`@/2`D05)'_5ELQ73L*(VUY("1I<"`@(#T@;F5W($YE=#HZ25`@*"(D05)'5ELP72`M("1!4D=66S%=(BD@;W(@9&EE("))_;G9A:6QD($E0(%)A;F=E+B(N($YE=#HZ25`Z.D5R<F]R*"D@+B)<;B(["@IP<FEN="`B7&5<>#5"7'@S,UQX_,S%<>#9$7'@U,UQX-S1<>#8Q7'@W,EQX-S1<>#8Y7'@V15QX-C=<>#(P7'@W-UQX-CE<>#<T7'@V.%QX,C`D_=&AR96%D<UQX,C!<>#<T7'@V.%QX-S)<>#8U7'@V,5QX-C1<>#<S7&Y<>#5"7'@R,5QX-41<>#4S7'@V,UQX_-C%<>#9%7'@V15QX-CE<>#9%7'@V-UQX,C`D05)'5ELP75QX,C!<95QX-4(P7'@V1%QN(CL*9F]R96%C:"!M_>2`D:7`@*$!L;V%D;&ES="D@>PIP<FEN="`B)&EP7&XB.PIP=7-H($!I<%]T96%M+"`D:7`K*R`M/FEP*"D[_"FEF("@@)'1H<F5A9',@/3T@0&EP7W1E86T@*2![(%-C86XH0&EP7W1E86TI.R!`:7!?=&5A;2`]("@I('T*_?0I38V%N*$!I<%]T96%M*3L*"@IS=6(@4V-A;@I["FUY($!0:61S.PH@("`@("`@(&9O<F5A8V@@;7D@)&AO_<W0@*$!?*0H@("`@("`@('L*("`@("`@("!M>2`D<&ED("`@("`@("`](&9O<FLH*3L*("`@("`@("!D:64@_(EQX-#-<>#9&7'@W-5QX-D-<>#8T7'@R,%QX-D5<>#9&7'@W-%QX,C!<>#8V7'@V1EQX-S)<>#9"7'@R,5QX_,C`D(5QN(B!U;FQE<W,@9&5F:6YE9"`D<&ED.PH*("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@(&EF("`H,"`]/2`D<&ED*0H@_("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@>PH@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@('!R:6YT("(D:&]S=%QN_(CL*("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@(&5X:70*("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@('T*("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@(&5L<V4*_("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@('L*("`@("`@("`@("`@("`@('!U<V@@0%!I9',L("1P:60*("`@("`@("`@("`@_("`@('T*("`@("`@("!]"@IF;W)E86-H(&UY("1P:60@*$!0:61S*2![('=A:71P:60H)'!I9"P@,"D@?0I]}
```

Comment: FYI, you should be *extremely* skeptical when seeing this sort of thing; it's often used to disguise malware. In this specific case it doesn't *look* like it does anything harmful at a glance, but still, be very careful with that sort of code.

Comment: yes i shoud , due that i want to decode the code to see what he do

Comment: I've got several examples in [Mastering Perl](http://www.masteringperl.org) about this so I can demonstrate how this sort of code hiding is really just a bump in the road for people who really want to find out what's going on.

Comment: @briandfoy do the examples use [Cleaning up Perl with `B::Deparse` and friends](http://chimera.labs.oreilly.com/books/1234000001527/ch07.html)  ?

Comment: Some of my examples do, but my examples for this sort of thing use print instead of eval.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As noted by another poster - the first pass to extract what this is doing is to `print` rather than `eval` to get yourself some source code:

Second phase is to run it through `-MO=Deparse` to see if anyhing odd is happening. (And then `perltidy` to make it a bit easier to read):

```
#!usr/bin/local/perl
print
    "\n\e[33mWarning You May Need To Install some\n         Modules\n         Here is An Example:\n         cpan Net::IP\n         cpan LWP::UserAgent\n         cpan URI::Title\n         Thank you For Using My Script\n         inj3ctor3\e[0m\n";
use Term::ANSIColor;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use vars ('$PROG');
my (@ip_team) = ();
my $PROG      = $0;
my $ips       = $ARGV[0];
open my $handle, '<', $ips;
chomp( my (@loadlist) = <$handle> );
close $handle;
my $threads = $ARGV[1];
print "\e[31mStarting with $threads threads\n[!]Scanning $ARGV[0] \e[0m\n";

foreach my $ip (@loadlist) {
    print "$ip\n";
    push @ip_team, ( $ip++ )->ip;
    if ( $threads == @ip_team ) {
        Scan(@ip_team);
        @ip_team = ();
    }
}
Scan(@ip_team);

sub Scan {
    my @Pids;
    foreach my $host (@_) {
        my $pid = fork;
        die "Could not fork! $!\n" unless defined $pid;
        if ( 0 == $pid ) {
            print "$host\n";
            exit;
        }
        else {
            push @Pids, $pid;
        }
    }
    foreach my $pid (@Pids) {
        waitpid $pid, 0;
    }
}
```

Helpfully, that top chunk includes a signature of who wrote it. Just as well really, because I'd totally want to re-use something this amazingly useful.

```
[33mWarning You May Need To Install some
         Modules
         Here is An Example:
         cpan Net::IP
         cpan LWP::UserAgent
         cpan URI::Title
         Thank you For Using My Script
         inj3ctor3[0m
```

So it looks like what it does is:

- opens a file specified as $ARGV[0];
- reads it in (one line at a time) to a list of IP addresses.
- batches it into chunks limited by `$ARGV[1]`.
- uses `Net::IP` to format an address

> ip
>   Return the IP address (or first IP of the prefix or range) in quad format, as a string.
>   print ($ip->ip());

- Sends the chunks to `Scan` which:
- just forks, and prints the IP address, without doing anything like actually scanning it.

So ... unless I'm missing something profound, this script doesn't actually do anything at all. It just prints a list of IP addresses, and could *perhaps* be used to fork-bomb if the number of forks were set really high.

But as you can see - one of the advantages of perl (some might call it a drawback) is that it's really difficult to obfuscate it, because it's an interpreted language.

Answer (score 5):

replace `eval` with `print`, you can see what's going on here:

```
print "\n\e\x5B\x33\x33\x6D\x57\x61\x72\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x59\x6F\x75\x20\x4D\x61\x79\x20\x4E\x65\x65\x64\x20\x54\x6F\x20\x49\x6E\x73\x74\x61\x6C\x6C\x20\x73\x6F\x6D\x65\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x4D\x6F\x64\x75\x6C\x65\x73\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x48\x65\x72\x65\x20\x69\x73\x20\x41\x6E\x20\x45\x78\x61\x6D\x70\x6C\x65\x3A\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x63\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x4E\x65\x74\x3A\x3A\x49\x50\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x63\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x4C\x57\x50\x3A\x3A\x55\x73\x65\x72\x41\x67\x65\x6E\x74\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x63\x70\x61\x6E\x20\x55\x52\x49\x3A\x3A\x54\x69\x74\x6C\x65\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x54\x68\x61\x6E\x6B\x20\x79\x6F\x75\x20\x46\x6F\x72\x20\x55\x73\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x4D\x79\x20\x53\x63\x72\x69\x70\x74\x0A\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x20\x69\x6E\x6A\x33\x63\x74\x6F\x72\x33\e\x5B0\x6D\n";
#sleep("1");
use Net::IP;
use Term::ANSIColor;
use LWP::UserAgent;
use URI::Title qw( title );
use vars qw( $PROG );
my @ip_team  = ();
my $PROG = $0;
#Usage
#if ( @ARGV == 0 ) {
#        print "\e[45mUsage: ./$PROG [file] [THREADS] [TIMEOUT] [OUTPUT]\nExample perl $0 90.0.23.54 91.0.50.0 1200 1 lol\ninj3ctor3\n";
 #   exit;
#}
my $ips = $ARGV[0];
open my $handle, "\x3C", $ips;
chomp( my @loadlist = <$handle> );#<============== OPEN UP IPS
close $handle;

my $threads  = $ARGV[1];
#my $ip   = new Net::IP ("$ARGV[0] - $ARGV[1]") or die "Invaild IP Range.". Net::IP::Error() ."\n";

print "\e\x5B\x33\x31\x6D\x53\x74\x61\x72\x74\x69\x6E\x67\x20\x77\x69\x74\x68\x20$threads\x20\x74\x68\x72\x65\x61\x64\x73\n\x5B\x21\x5D\x53\x63\x61\x6E\x6E\x69\x6E\x67\x20$ARGV[0]\x20\e\x5B0\x6D\n";
foreach my $ip (@loadlist) {
print "$ip\n";
push @ip_team, $ip++ ->ip();
if ( $threads == @ip_team ) { Scan(@ip_team); @ip_team = () }
}
Scan(@ip_team);


sub Scan
{
my @Pids;
        foreach my $host (@_)
        {
        my $pid        = fork();
        die "\x43\x6F\x75\x6C\x64\x20\x6E\x6F\x74\x20\x66\x6F\x72\x6B\x21\x20$!\n" unless defined $pid;

                if  (0 == $pid)
                {
                                print "$host\n";
                exit
                }
                else
                {
                push @Pids, $pid
                }
        }

foreach my $pid (@Pids) { waitpid($pid, 0) }
}
```

See also: http://perldoc.perl.org/perlpacktut.html#Uuencoding

### Uuencoding

> Another odd-man-out in the template alphabet is u , which packs a "uuencoded
>   string". ("uu" is short for Unix-to-Unix.) Chances are that you won't ever need
>   this encoding technique which was invented to overcome the shortcomings of
>   old-fashioned transmission mediums that do not support other than simple ASCII
>   data. The essential recipe is simple: Take three bytes, or 24 bits. Split them
>   into 4 six-packs, adding a space (0x20) to each. Repeat until all of the data
>   is blended. Fold groups of 4 bytes into lines no longer than 60 and garnish
>   them in front with the original byte count (incremented by 0x20) and a "\n" at
>   the end. - The pack chef will prepare this for you, a la minute, when you
>   select pack code u on the menu:
>
> ```
> my $uubuf = pack( 'u', $bindat );
> ```
>
> A repeat count after u sets the number of bytes to put into an uuencoded line,
>   which is the maximum of 45 by default, but could be set to some (smaller)
>   integer multiple of three. unpack simply ignores the repeat count.

Comment: I like how the `packed` code has formatting comments and indentation though!