# How to open and edit encrypted perl script?

Tags: perl, encryption, perl-module

I have a perl script that is encrypted. This script can be compiled only if [Filter::decrypt](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filter::decrypt) is installed. I have that Filter and I installed it and the script is compiled with no problem, but now I want to open that script with some text editor and edit it.

Can someone help me and tell me how can I do this?

Comment: `perl -MO=Deparse script.pl`?

Comment: Are you trying to circumvent licensing restrictions? [The module's documentation](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filter::decrypt) lists some of the ways you can access the source code. Try those first, and later revise your question to show what you have tried etc. Voting to close.

Comment: I can't give an answer without some more detail - my 'answer' would be to refer you to `Mastering Perl` which has a chapter on de-obfuscation. http://www.masteringperl.org/

Or see this answer to something similar: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30287667/how-can-i-de-obfuscate-or-decode-this-perl-code/30299790#30299790

If you want a specific answer, we're going to need a bit more detail.

Comment: I am totally new at perl. Everything that I know is that when I try to open the perl scripts with some text editor I can see only the first line of the code.
 use Filter::decrypt:
So I installed Filter-1.37 that it was given together with the perl script. after installing this filter the perl script can be compiled but I can not open with text editor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best option: Just edit your unencrypted copy and reinstall it.

Alternative: Use [`decr`](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RURBAN/Filter-1.54/decrypt/decr) (comes with Filter::decrypt) to decrypt an encrypted file.

Answer (score 3):

Pretty fundamentally - it's extremely difficult to make a script unreadable, simply because perl is an interpreted language. Exactly how to disentangle something is more a question of how it got tangled in the first place.

So I would suggest as a first port of call - have a look through [`Mastering Perl`](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/mastering-perl/9780596527242/ch07s03.html) which has a whole chapter on the subject of disassembling perl code.

However if you just look at the [`Filter::decrypt`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Filter::decrypt) module page, it indicates several places which the module simply cannot cover - you can only truly 'protect' code if you've control of the perl interpreter in the first place. However the things it suggests are:

> Strip the Perl binary to remove all symbols.
>
> Build the decrypt extension using static linking. If the extension is provided as a dynamic module, there is nothing to stop someone from linking it at run time with a modified Perl binary.
>
> Do not build Perl with -DDEBUGGING. If you do then your source can be retrieved with the `-Dp` command line option.
>
> The sample filter contains logic to detect the DEBUGGING option.
>
> Do not build Perl with C debugging support enabled.
>
> Do not implement the decryption filter as a sub-process (like the cpp source filter). It is possible to peek into the pipe that connects to the sub-process.
>
> Check that the Perl Compiler isn't being used.
>
> There is code in the BOOT: section of decrypt.xs that shows how to detect the presence of the Compiler. Make sure you include it in your module.
>
> Assuming you haven't taken any steps to spot when the compiler is in use and you have an encrypted Perl script called "myscript.pl", you can get access the source code inside it using the perl Compiler backend, like this
>
> `perl -MO=Deparse myscript.pl`
>
> Note that even if you have included the BOOT: test, it is still possible to use the Deparse module to get the source code for individual subroutines.

So:

```
perl -MO=Deparse yourscript
perl -Dp yourscript
```

If these don't work - look at your local copy of `Filter::decrypt` and alter it so it prints the decrypted result.

Comment: I have tried perl -MO=Deparse Email.pm and this is the error I receive:

Aborting, Compiler detected at /usr/lib/perl/5.18/DynaLoader.pm line 207.
Compilation failed in require at Email.pm line 1.
BEGIN failed--compilation aborted at Email.pm line 1.
use Filter::decrypt;